# How to call one applications angularjs from another application and retrieve the

Tags: java, angularjs, struts2

#### The Background

I have two applications, which will be referred to as Alpha and Beta. Alpha and Beta are both Angular/Struts2 apps. Alpha is an application that handles searching for classes and Beta is an application thats responsible enrolling in those class, dropping them, swapping etc. Alpha will be both open to the Public and those with Accounts, while Beta will be strictly those with accounts.

#### The Problem

Some of the functionality in Beta should be visible in Alpha when signed in, such as adding a class that was searched for into a cart. I would like to keep that functionality within the Beta application to separate concerns. We want the two applications to be seamless so we want to avoid a redirect to Beta.

#### The Question

How can I call Beta's Angular functions for retrieving the data from struts actions, in Alpha's Angular functions?

### The Flow

```
Alpha                                              Beta
```

```
User clicks add to cart
```

```
Alpha sends information to Beta     ----------->   Beta Receives Information
```

```
                                                   Beta performs some actions
```

```
Alpha receives Response             

User is informed of response
```

Comment: Probably you should do it via ajax.

Comment: Would you happen to have an example of how to do this via ajax?